# Is there any Win32 API to get the total number of running processes on Windows 10?

Tags: winapi

Right now, I use `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()` to calculate the number of running processes by traversing a snapshot of all processes. Is there any API to get the number directly, instead of traversing?

Comment: No, there is no such API. And even if there were, that number could become stale the moment you retrieve it. With the snapshot API, that is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`EnumProcesses`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-enumprocesses) and divide by 4. Internally this calls the NT API and traverses last time I looked but that was a long time ago...

Comment: This is about as close as you can get to a single-counter API. Just be aware that you have to either overallocate a large array, or call it in a loop, in order to get an accurate count.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Even sadder, this was the only public API in NT4 and it internally grabs all the undocumented process info and throws all of it away except for the PIDs.

Comment: The performance counters or WMI might be able to give you a number but those probably have more overhead. I don't believe the kernel stores a count, only a linked list of processes.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned, there is no proper API to get the numbers directly, instead of traversing.

For more details to get the list of running processes, I suggest you could refer to the example:

[Taking a Snapshot and Viewing Processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/toolhelp/taking-a-snapshot-and-viewing-processes)